# kdump doesn't produce core dump after buggy module is loaded

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-panic, core-dump

I am running kernel 3.14.4 on Fedora 18.
I am experimenting with a kernel module I am making.
The module has a bug (at least one) and crashes the kernel.
Sometimes I see a stack trace on my frozen screen (if I am lucky) by tailing
the kernel log (`tail -f /var/log/messages`).
From what I see, it's a NULL pointer dereference.

Since luck does not provide for productivity I configured kdump,
enabled it on boot, and tested that in fact it does create a kernel
dump upon a sample panic (`echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`), which I can see after it reboots through the crash utility.

But when I test my module the kernel crashes and no dump is generated.

What can I do better?